# Validate Siri input with javascript? Is there any Siri-related event/trigger?

Tags: javascript, iphone, siri

I wonder if it is possible to validate with JS some Siri-driven (or Android Speech Recognition software) input on mobile devices.

I have a "input type=text" object, but I need to enable only digits (numbers). 
I'm using keydown/keyup to trap and delete keyboard inputs but if the user enables Siri and then talks, the textfield is pupulated with strings...

Is there any event I can listen for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following is true, you pretty much solved the problem: "if the content of the input changed in X ms and no key has been typed in X ms, then a software aid has been used".

Or, put another way, you can know if the text changed and the user typed something (or not)

Comment: I'm not marking the question solved just because I'd like to know if there is an event I could listen.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `input type='number'`?

Here is a list of support.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: No I cannot. I could use type=tel but it doesn't show the siri switch on button on the keyboard. I'm stuck on the type=text.

Comment: Ok, let's say I can do it. It seems it doesn't make any difference.